# Compare two lines in same file

Tags: linux, unix, diff, cmp, uniq

Given a file like the following:-

```
01/09/2005
02/09/2005
03/09/2006
03/09/2006
```

I wish to compare if the last two lines are the same, and return a 1 if so or a 0 if they are not.

I can get the last two using a `cat tail -2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tail -n 2 filename.txt | uniq | wc -l
```

This will yield `1` for identical lines, `2` for different.

Comment: My solution is the same! Except that I added a check for files with < 2 lines.

Comment: My solution is the same! Except that I added a `exit` statement to return the codes as requested in the "question".

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
lc=`wc -l filename.txt | cut -d " " -f1`
if [ $lc -ge 2 ]
then 
    ulc=`tail -n 2 filename.txt | uniq | wc -l`
    if [ $ulc -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "Last two lines are identical"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[ `cat | tail -n 2 | uniq | wc -l` -eq "1" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Replace `echo` by `exit` to make it the exit value. Used `echo` just for quicker testing.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ `cat | tail -n 2 | uniq | wc -l` -eq "1" ] && exit 1
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -n '$!h;${G;/\(.*\)\n\1$/{s/.*/1/p;q};s/.*/0/p}' filename.txt
```